# JavaScript Not Generate Accurate Result If User Doesn't Fill TextField 3?

Tags: javascript, html

I Wanted to create a function of `Max`, `Min`, `Avg`, `Sum` but the problem is When the user enters numbers in all textfields it gives result accurate.
But When TextField 3 is empty it doesn't give an accurate result. I try to handle this thing but nothing happen.

```js
function maxer() {

  var max = 0,
    min = 0,
    sum = 0,
    avg, power = "<p>MAX:";
  var arrayName = [3];
  arrayName[0] = document.getElementById('number1').value;
  arrayName[1] = document.getElementById('number2').value;
  arrayName[2] = document.getElementById('number3').value;

  if (arrayName[2] == "") {
    arrayName[2] = 0;
  }

  var f = Math.max(arrayName[0], arrayName[1], arrayName[2]);
  max = f;

  var g = Math.min(arrayName[0], arrayName[1], arrayName[2]);
  min = g;


  for (var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; sum = sum + parseInt(arrayName[i]), avg = sum / arrayName.length,
    i++);

  power += max + "</p>" + "<br/>";
  power += "<p>Min:";
  power += min + "</p>" + "<br/>";
  power += "<p>SUM:";
  power += sum + "</p>" + "<br/>";
  power += "<p>AVERAGE:";
  power += avg + "</p>" + "<br/>";
  document.getElementById('mmsa').innerHTML = power;
}
```

```html
Enter Number 1: <input id="number1" type="text" name="number1" placeholder="Enter Number 1" />
Enter Number 2: <input id="number2" type="text" name="number2" placeholder="Enter Number 2" />
Enter Number 3: <input id="number3" type="text" name="number3" placeholder="Enter Number 3" />
<button type="button" onClick="maxer()">Click This To Operate</button>
<p id="mmsa"></p>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, but why do you initialize it as `[3]` instead of `[]`?

Comment: There's no `id="mmsa"` in your HTML.

Comment: @Barmar - I just added it for him so the snippet would work

Comment: When field 3 is emp[ty you act as if it was 0. So you're averaging 3 numbers even if the user entered only 2.

Comment: @Zain Khan - What Barmar said. The results are accurate, it's treating blank text fields as "0". It even looks like you were expecting this, since you have this code: `if (arrayName[2] == "") { arrayName[2] = 0; }`. How do you want it to work? Ignore the blank text fields and only handle the entered numbers?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry i forget about id i added it

Comment: How Ignore the blank text fields and only handle the entered numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, you need to only process the array elements that contain values. Ideally, your array should only be a big as it needs to be to hold the valid input values. Oriol's solution does this in a really clean and compact way, but might be hard to understand if you're new to Javascript. If you'd like something closer to your original solutions, here's a (somewhat less clean) alternative that uses as much of your original code as possible:

```js
function maxer() {

    var max = 0,
      min = 0,
      sum = 0,
      avg, power = "<p>MAX:";
    var arrayName = [];
    for(var i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        if(document.getElementById('number' + i).value.trim().length > 0)
        {
            arrayName[arrayName.length] = parseInt(document.getElementById('number' + i).value);
        }
    }
    
    if(arrayName.length > 0)
    {
        max = arrayName[0];
        min = arrayName[0];
        sum = arrayName[0];    

        for (var j = 1; j < arrayName.length; j++)
        {
            max = Math.max(max, arrayName[j]);
            min = Math.min(min, arrayName[j]);
            sum += arrayName[j];
        }

        var avg = sum / arrayName.length;

        power += max + "</p>" + "<br/>";
        power += "<p>Min:";
        power += min + "</p>" + "<br/>";
        power += "<p>SUM:";
        power += sum + "</p>" + "<br/>";
        power += "<p>AVERAGE:";
        power += avg + "</p>" + "<br/>";
        document.getElementById('mmsa').innerHTML = power;
    }
}
```

```html
Enter Number 1: <input id="number1" type="text" name="number1" placeholder="Enter Number 1" />
Enter Number 2: <input id="number2" type="text" name="number2" placeholder="Enter Number 2" />
Enter Number 3: <input id="number3" type="text" name="number3" placeholder="Enter Number 3" />
<button type="button" onClick="maxer()">Click This To Operate</button>
<p id="mmsa"></p>
```

Comment: @Zain Khan -  I've heard good things about "Javascript: The good parts", but haven't read it myself yet.

Comment: @Zain Khan - That's a very broad question. In a nutshell, I'd say: 1. Read everything you can get your hands on. 2. Study code from other people's projects (check Github.com to find some). 3. Research anything you don't understand (like Oriol's answer). 4. Keep practicing; code all the time. Some concepts just won't click until you've worked with them a long time. This question might help you: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8721/how-do-i-improve-my-coding-skills

Answer (score 2):

```js
function maxer() {
  var numbers = [].map.call( // Get strings from the inputs
    document.querySelectorAll('.number'),
    function(el) {
      return el.value;
    }
  ).filter(function(str) { // Filter out empty strings
    return str;
  }).map(Number); // Convert to numbers

  var max = Math.max.apply(void 0, numbers),
      min = Math.min.apply(void 0, numbers),
      sum = numbers.reduce(function(a,b) {
        return a + b;
      }),
      avg = sum / numbers.length;
  
  document.getElementById('mmsa').innerHTML = 
    "<p>Max: " + max + "</p>"
    +"<p>Min: " + min + "</p>"
    +"<p>Sum: " + sum + "</p>"
    +"<p>Average: " + avg + "</p>";
}
document.querySelector('button').onclick = maxer;
```

```html
<p>Enter Number 1: <input class="number" type="text" /></p>
<p>Enter Number 2: <input class="number" type="text" /></p>
<p>Enter Number 3: <input class="number" type="text" /></p>
<button type="button">Click This To Operate</button>
<div id="mmsa"></div>
```

Comment: i don't know jquery can you tell me some details in above function how it works or do it in javascript

Comment: @ZainKhan I didn't use jQuery. What exactly does confuse you? Array methods: [`map`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`reduce`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)? Math methods: [`max`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), [`min`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)? ...

Comment: ... Function methods: [`apply`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)? DOM selector methods: [`querySelectorAll`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), [`querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)?